# Teletubby-type creatures turn out to have eldritch connection

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

This is a tip of the tongue thing. It was either a movie or a TV series that I watched within the last 5 years. There are these Teletubby like characters, I think under the control of a major corporation. I want to say that they are all colors of red and purple. Much like the teletubbies, they appear as if they have humans in plush costumes, but at some point, the protagonist realizes that there are other entities within them, or at least some of them. I want to say that he comes up on a scene where they are having either an orgy or a murder, and he knocks off, or pulls off, one of their heads.

I want to say that another character in the series, an actress, possibly with dwarfism, is revealed to have been one of the legitimate actors in the costumes, but I think I might be mixing that up with Vanessa in *[Skins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skins_(2017_film))*.

I'm pretty sure that the main character who makes the discovery was a white male, and I think he was speaking English. I think there was also an earlier scene where a child goes missing during one of the live performances, with a scene where his mother is trying to find him in the crowd. I think that, in that case, the child is found safe and sound.

Comment: There was an episode of Angel very similar to your description. The fuzzy actors (demons, I think, though they look like muppets). Angel himself was magically changed to a puppet, himself. Children did disappear, but through their TVs.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This sounds like [Happy!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy!_(TV_series)) to me. The main plot of the first season is the main character (white male, English speaking) looking for a girl who was abducted at a live performance of a child's entertainer - she was at the concert with her mother.

There was a scene with a Teletubby (a Wishee) orgy, and at one point one takes off its "head" to reveal something decidedly not human. Here is an image of the Wishee:

[image: Wishee]

There was no dwarf that I can recall.

### Wishee Fight

Comment: The "dwarf" part reminded me of an episode from the TV series "Special Unit 2" in which an actual dwarf (the show had sci-fi creatures in it) participated to a show for kids.

Comment: The eldritch connection fits, as the creatures turn out to be minions of a demon.